# whats wrong with this code to print prime numbers within range

Tags: c

```
//to print prime number within range
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    int i,upper,n,k,l,prime;
    int primes[300];
    primes[0]=2;
    printf("enter the upper limit:");
    scanf("%d",&upper);
    l=0;
    for(i=5;i=upper;i+=2){
        prime=0;
        for(k=0;k=l;k++){
            if(i%primes[k]==0){// if not prime set prime=0
                prime==1;
                break;
}
}
    if (prime==0){
        l++;
        primes[l]=i;//else store as array
}
}
for (n=0;n=l;n++){
    printf("%d",primes[n]);}//print the elements in the array
return 0;
// end of the function}
```

why doesn't it work?in python, it works fine when I use a list. But here it doesn't even run past the input.what is the mistake I have done. I have already compiled it too

Comment: what do you observe? This looks fishy: `for(k=0;k=l;k++)`

Comment: `for(i=5;i=upper;i+=2){` looks very odd. Do you mean `i <= upper`?

Comment: `for` is like a `while` - it runs as long as the middle condition holds true.

Comment: bear in mind that 2 and 3 are prime, so your results may not be correct

Answer (score 0):

1. the line `for(i=5;i=upper;i+=2){` should be `for (i = 3; i < upper; i += 2) {`
2. the line `for(k=0;k=l;k++){` should be `for (k = 2; k != i; ++k)`
3. the line `if(i%primes[k]==0` should be `if(i%k == 0)`

The following `code` could work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

#define N 300

int main(){
  int i,upper,k,l;
  int primes[N];
  primes[0] = 2;
  printf("enter the upper limit:");
  scanf("%d", &upper);
  if (upper > N)
    return -1;
  l = 0;
  for (i = 3; i < upper; i += 2) {
    for (k = 2; k != i; ++k)
      if(i%k == 0)
        break;
    if (k == i)
      primes[l++] = i;
  }
  for (i = 0; i != l; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", primes[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if `upper` is 16, or any even number?  your outer loop should be `for(i = 3; i < upper; i += 2)`.

Comment: why doesn't it print all of the prime numbers?
http://prntscr.com/lr3882